# Javascript code not working - showing and hiding divs

Tags: javascript, jsf, accordion

i have the following javascript

```
function toggle_profile(source, target) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(target);
    var text = document.getElementById(source);
    if (ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "+  ";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "-  ";
    }
}
```

and the following is in the html:

```
 <c:forEach items="#{inventory.categories}" var="c">
       <a id="#{c.name}" href="javascript:toggle_profile(#{c.name}, #{c.name}div);">+ </a>
<h:outputText value="   " />
       <h:commandLink action="#{inventory.getBooks(c)}" value="#{c.name}" style="font-weight: bold" />
       <br />
       <div id="#{c.name}div" style="display: none">
           <c:forEach items="#{c.subCategories}" var="s">
               <i> <h:commandLink action="#{inventory.getBooks(s)}" value="#{s.name}" />
               </i>
               <br />
           </c:forEach>
           <br />
       </div>
   </c:forEach>
```

The text is displayed successfully but the + links do nothing.

Comment: `document.getElementById(target);` instead of `document.getElementById(traget);`?

Comment: fixed it but unfortunately that didn't solve the problem

Comment: is the div id id="#{c.name}div" resolved to a proper id when you look at the source of the page?

Comment: When having problems with JS code in JSF, always first look at JSF-generated HTML output by rightclick, *View Source* in your webbrowser. You'll see that the JS function which you attempted to specify in `href` attribute is **nowhere** present there. JavaScript runs in client side, working on the HTML DOM tree. JavaScript does not run in webserver, working on the JSF source code or so.

Comment: yes the id's are being set correctly

Comment: BalusC what do you reccomend i do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change you javascript function with following,

```
function toggle_profile(source, target) {
var ele = document.getElementById(target);
var text = document.getElementById(source);
if (ele.style.display == "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "-  ";
} else {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "+  ";      
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You use `<h:commandLink>` in a wrong way. Firstly, it doesn't have `href` attribute: it will be generated by JSF and will always be `#`, so in fact *your JS code is never called*. Secondly, it is designed to post a form by the bound `onclick` handler, and not to do some JavaScript manipulations.

To do what you want, just use a plain HTML `a` element, or even a `div` with a specified onclick handler.

Comment: i swapped it to an <a> tag and the id's are rendered correctly but nothign changed either way